# Angular : onClick on html element according to its class

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular6, angular2-template

Under my Angular App, I'm using some 3rd library widget which is rendering in my component.

**My template is:**

```
<div>
  <myWidGet></myWidGet>
</div>
```

Inside `myWidGet` there some button element that I want handle their events.
The button have those classes : `.dx-edit-row .dx-command-edit .dx-link-save`

so i i do that :

```
export class myClass AfterViewInit { 

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef){}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.dx-edit-row .dx-command-edit .dx- 
link-save').on('click', (e) => {
      alert('test');
    });
  }

}
```

My purpose is to **get reference** to my button **and handle the click** event from it.

**Suggestions?**

Comment: I think Im abit confused.
why would you use native JS queryselector inside angular?
you cant get any interaction with those buttons?

Comment: Maybe get `myWidGet` with `ViewChild` and try getting button with `querySelector`. Although, this way of doing things is not "Angular" way, that button should emit an `Output` event...

Comment: You could set a `click` event handler on the `div` and check the classes of the `event.target` to determine if the widget button was clicked (assuming that the `click` event propagation was not stopped).

Comment: See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qx9emq) for an example of event delegation, as suggested in my previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally the 3rd party widget should provide a click handler like so:

```
<myWidGet (click)="myFunction($event)"></myWidGet>
```

and in the controller:

```
myFunction(evt) {
  const target = evt.target
  console.log('test')
}
```

However, if they do not expose click handlers then I would seriously consider not using the widget.

If want to use the widget anyway then do this using jQuery:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  $('.dx-edit-row.dx-command-edit.dx-link-save').on('click', (evt) => {
    const target = evt.target
    console.log('test')
  });
}
```

The above assumes ALL these classes are present on the same button.

Or just use vanilla JS.

If the buttons are not available on `ngAfterViewInit()` then you could do this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    const button = $('.dx-edit-row.dx-command-edit.dx-link-save')
    // if button is ready
    if (button) {
      // add click handlers
      button.on('click', (evt) => {
        const target = evt.target
        console.log('test')
      });
      // stop polling
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
  }, 100)
}
```

Comment: i ve tried to do it with jquery : the problem that , this button appears after a while (it s a table where i should open some dropdowns to see the button) , so i can t get the console.log working

Comment: ok then if the buttons are not available in ngOnViewInit() you will have to poll, i'll add an example to my answer - this code will keep firing until the buttons are ready and then add the click handler and then stop firing, this is not great but this is what happens if you do not use professional 3rd party libs

Comment: i'm using devextereme-angular of DevExpress and for some widget (datagrid) , there is a lack for an edit event

Comment: heres the link for that lib, actually we use it at work and it is a good lib - https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/CellEditingAndEditingAPI/Angular/Light/

Comment: I've never done editing with it but I believe the data is two way bound, so when you make changes to the datagrid data in the controller the data in the datagrid updates and vice versa, maybe your controller data is updating and thus you do not need to handle the edit event?

Comment: when you use a datagrid with columns which all refers to cellTemplates , the event "onUpdating" of the datagrid would not detect the changes and  will not fire , and there is no way to trigger it ( i need it to send data to WS)

Comment: are the buttons in the cellTemplates? prob not but if so add (click) to the buttons there - if not polling may be the only solution - all the best

Comment: sorry it is ngAfterViewInit my apologies

Answer (score 3):

Accessing DOM elements using jQuery is not really a good practice. Use `ElementRef` with `Renderer2` instead. Also, there's nothing like `ngOnViewInit` in Angular. It's `ngAfterViewInit`.

Once the View loads, inside the `ngAfterViewInit`, you can get access to the `HTMLElement` using the `nativeElement` on `ElementRef` instance. You should explicitly typecast it into `HTMLElement` so as to get intellisence.

You can then call `querySelector` on it and pass it the classes. This will give you the button element.

Now you use `Renderer2`'s instances' `listen` method. This takes three args:

1. The element you want to listen to events on(`btnElement`).
2. The Name of the event(`click`).
3. The callback function.

This would translate to code like:

```
constructor(
  private el: ElementRef,
  private renderer: Renderer2
) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  const btnElement = (<HTMLElement>this.el.nativeElement)
    .querySelector('.dx-edit-row.dx-command-edit.dx-link-save');

  this.renderer.listen(btnElement, 'click', () => {
    alert('Buton was clicked');
  });
}
```

Here's a [**Working StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-get-el-by-class-name?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: `ElementRef' isn't a so better practice

Comment: @CristianTraìna, do you have any mention of that somewhere? I'd like to know more about it. I just feel it's better than polluting your Angular code with jQuery.

Comment: @SiddAjmera how to do , if my buttonons are not appeared afterViewInit (i would open a dropdown to see the button) ? .. of course without refereing to the click of dropdown opening

Comment: You mean your buttons are not present in the DOM on View Load?

Comment: @SiddAjmera you shouldn't just query an element inside a method. Direct access to DOM, in angular, is considered a bad practice. It's better if you just use the default (click) event handler, the angular way

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the third party widget using Angular Directive. It will allow to access DOM element and attach listeners using renderer2.

```
<myWidGet customEvents></myWidGet>
```

**Directive:**

```
@Directive({
   selector: '[customEvents]'
})
export class CustomEventsDirective implements OnInit {
    private element: any;
    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
        this.element = el.nativeElement;
    }
    ngOnInit() {

       const btnElement = this.element.querySelector('.dx-edit-row.dx-command-edit.dx-link-save');

       this.renderer.listen(btnElement, 'click', () => {
         alert('Buton was clicked');
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: that amazing , but it lack something :  my button didn appear onInti of the widegt (it appears after some dropodown opening inside the same widget , how to do it ?

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '__zone_symbol__addEventListener' of null

Comment: You can handle this using *ngIf. Set the boolean to true  based on ur condition.

Comment: u ven got the ideaa . The button inside the widget is not show since the init of the widget , so that i ve got the last error message . How may i initialize the vent listener when the button appears

Comment: i moved those logic to 'AfterViewInit' life cycle hook

Comment: Directives don't have `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook. They don't have any hook related to Content or View as they don't have a content or view.